# trouble with query to fetch next and previous posts

Tags: query-posts

I'm new to wordpress. I'm having trouble with a query I wrote to fetch the previous and next posts. ( I check

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date < ( SELECT post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = {$id} ) LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date > ( SELECT post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE ID =  {$id} ) LIMIT 1
";

$wpdb->query($sql);

$arrPosts = $wpdb->last_result;
```

But I only get one post in $arrPosts. ( I know there are more than two). What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$arrPosts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

That said, note that there also is an API to get these two. See in particular:

```
get_next_post()
get_previous_post()
```

Comment: Oh, and mind the {$id} thingy. Be sure to cast it to int, if used as is. Or use $wpdb->prepare().

Comment: I do an is_numeric() beforehand.

Comment: `get_next_post()` and `get_previous_post()` didn't work for me -- I get `NULL` for both values. I'm using `wp-load.php` to get access to wordpress data. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Setting up post data, maybe? Either use the WP standard loop formula with `if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();` , or populate the $post variable with your post object and calling `setup_postdata($post)` before trying to use these functions.